# what's the difference between -C and gzipping a mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

I want to do a mysqldump directly to my remotehost. I've seen suggestions to use the -c switch or use gzip to compress the data on the fly (and not in a file). What's the difference between the two? How do I know if both machines support the -C switch? How would I do a gzip on the fly? I am using linux on both machines.

```
mysqldump -C -u root -p database_name | mysql -h other-host.com database_name
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, -C compresses the sql code while it is being sent from the source mysql server to the destination server where your dumping the sql, then it uncompresses it on the destination server, and saves the uncompressed file on the (usually) hard disk. While gzipping would result in a gzipped (compressed) file being saved on the hard disk.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `-C` option uses compression that may be present in the MySQL client-server protocol.  Gzip'ing would use the `gzip` utility in a pipeline.  I'm pretty sure that the latter would not do any good since the compression and uncompression would occur on the same machine in this case.  If the machine that you are dumping from is local, then the `-C` option is probably just wasting CPU cycles - it compresses the protocol messages between `mysqldump` and the `mysqld` daemon.

The only command pipeline that might make sense here is something like:

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name | mysql -C -h other-host -Ddatabase_name -B
```

The output of `mysqldump` is going to the pipeline which the `mysql` command-line client will read.  The `-C` option tells `mysql` to compress the messages that it is sending to `other-host`.  The `-B` option disables buffering and interactive behavior in the `mysql` client which might speed things up a little more.

It would probably be faster to do something like:

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name | gzip > dump.gz
scp dump.gz user@other-host:/tmp
ssh user@other-host "gunzip /tmp/dump.gz | mysql -Ddatabase_name -B; rm /tmp/dump.gz"
```

Provided that you have SSH running on the other machine anyway.

Comment: Where can I find more info on -B? I'm not able to find anything. Does it act like --quick?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: "mysqldump -C -u root -p database_name | mysql -h other-host -Ddatabase_name -B"?

Comment: No, the `-C` option compresses the communication between the client application (`mysqldump` or `mysql`) and the server (`mysqld`).  Running `mysqldump -C` and connecting to *localhost* compresses tells the MySQL daemon to compress the data that it is sending to `mysqldump` which then uncompresses it before writing to the output pipe.  Using the compress option only makes sense when the client application and daemon are on separate hosts.

Comment: [`-B`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_batch), or `--batch`, is similar to `--quick`.  It disables the usage of the history file.

Answer (score 0):

I always read the man pages for these types of things. If you look at the [man pages for mysqldump](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysqldump/) you can see that the `-C` (thats a **capital** C) flag makes the mysqldump compress all data **in transit only**. this makes it stream compressed but arrive, as you will see it, uncompressed. You could dump the file to the local system then transfer a gzip of everything at once too.

from the man page:

```
   o   --compress, -C

       Compress all information sent between the client and the server if
       both support compression.
```

Comment: "...but arrive, as you will see it, uncompressed"...what does that mean? How does it get from compressed to uncompressed? Is using the -C switch essentially doing a gzip on the fly?

Comment: "....if both support compression." How do I know if both of my servers support compression?

Comment: I can't assume it's doing gzip but it does compress it on the fly.